# Alternative ways to set SSL_CERT_FILE

Tags: ruby

I am trying to set `ENV[SSL_CERT_FILE]` in my ruby code. However, it seems that what I set this variable to will only take effect if it's set before `OpenSSL` is loaded by some arbitrary gem.

For example, here is a piece of sample code from a gem I am using:

```
require 'adal' # https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby
ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = 'path/to/pem/file.pem'
```

The above will discard what I have set `ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE']`, presumably because `OpenSSL` was loaded before the environment variable has been set (it is loaded in the `adal` gem).

However, this works:

```
ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = 'path/to/pem/file.pem'
require 'adal'
```

This is a simple example. It is not possible to use this solution.

I also cannot set a system variable either -- this is a gem I am building for my company which many developers will use and it's best if I avoid having them download a `cacert.pem` file and set a system variable pointing to it.

Are there any alternative solutions to this issue?

Comment: Try [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

Comment: How and where do you think `ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE']` is used?

Comment: Well, from what I researched, it's being used within the `OpenSSL` library. That gets loaded in when you use `net/http`. As far as when `net/http` gets loaded within my project, I don't exactly know. It may be by a third party gem.